# File exists but download code throws FileNotFoundException

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I want the user to be able to download `.docx` documents from a website. The file exists and path is correct because file exists is returning true, but in the view, browser says `FileNotFoundException`.

If I copy the error path and past into explorer address box, it opens the document.

```
public IActionResult DownloadDocument(int docID) 
{
    if (System.IO.File.Exists(@"C:\Users\Folder1\source\repos\Folder2\Folder3\Contents\Folder4\CustomerFeedback.docx"))
         return File(@"C:\Users\Folder1\source\repos\Folder2\Folder3\Contents\Folder4\CustomerFeedback.docx", "application/docx", "CustomerFeedback.docx");
}
```

Comment: Try doing Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\Folder1\source\repos\Folder2\Folder3\Contents\Folder4")

Comment: Where did you get that `application/docx` was a valid MIME type? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4212861/what-is-a-correct-mime-type-for-docx-pptx-etc

Comment: Hi Ardila. I get that code from https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/rahul4_saxena/download-file-in-mvc-4/

Answer (score 2):

Try using the proper MIME type for DOCX - application/docx will not be served up by IIS as it's not a registered content type.

Content Type for DOCX: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4212908/175679

Comment: Thank you Silver Ninja I updated and it doesn't give me error now but the download didn't start. It is just opening the view page. I thought this code starts a file download.